# Splitting a string of numbers

Tags: python, string, split

I was wondering how i cant split this string for a game i'm assigned. The player is supposed to input an x and y value for a 60x15 grid.

```
answer = input('enter an x and y coordinate with a space between')
```

ill make my x equal to 30 and my y equal to 7

```
playerAnswer = []
answer = '30 7'
answer.split(' ')
playerAnswer.append((player[0], player[1]))
```

when I do this i get `playerAnswer` to be `['3', '0']`
is there any way to make the `playerAnswer` to become `['30', '0']`?

Comment: What does your `player` list look like?

Comment: Do you really want the response to be '30' instead of 30? Also, `player` is not defined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the return value of `split`. `str.split` does not modify a string in place (strings are actually immutable), but *returns* a list.

Demo:

```
>>> answer = '30 7'
>>> answer_split = answer.split(' ')
>>> answer
'30 7'
>>> answer_split
['30', '7']
>>> answer_split[0]
'30'
>>> answer_split[1]
'7'
```

In case you want actual integers, you can do:

```
>>> answer_split = [int(x) for x in answer.split(' ')]
>>> answer_split
[30, 7]
```

I am not exactly sure why you are indexing into `player` instead of the result of `split` when appending to `playerAnswer`, so that is likely another bug.

Note: if you just want to split by any whitespace, you can omit the argument `' '` to `split`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = [int(i) for i in answer.split()]
>>> a
30
>>> b
7
```

Or, if you really want text:

```
playerAnswer = []
playerAnswer.append(tuple(i for i in answer.split()))

>>> playerAnswer
[('30', '9')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most pythonic way to achieve this is:

```
>>> x, y = map(int, input('enter an x and y coordinate with a space between').split())
>>> x
30
>>> y
7
```

Now coming to the issue with your code:

```
playerAnswer.append((player[0], player[1]))
```

replace `player` with `answer` as you are storing the splitted values in `answer` variable (also I do not see any `player` variable in the code you mentioned, so I am not sure what it stores. But I am sure you don not need that). Below lines should work fine.

```
playerAnswer.append((answer[0], answer[1]))
```

Also, I do not think you need `30` and `7` as `str`. For converting it into `int`, I am using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function.